# Bash nested conditionals for network check

Tags: bash, nested, conditional-statements

I have a remote OS X machine. It uses VPN software (VPN Tracker) to create a tunnel to a server. I currently have an Applescript to check if the tunnel is up; if it's up, wait one minute then do it again, if it isn't up, run the command to make it active. It works great.

I've written a bash script that sends a LOT of files from the remote site to the server. For the most part it works fine (takes 8+ hours to send ~10,000 files nightly), scheduled by cron, for all intents and purposes, just needs some tweeks.(that's a separate issue)

However, I want to add a network check to the script before the file transfer stuff starts, cause there's no sense in starting if the VPN isn't up. I'm not a bash expert and want to see if my "logic" is correct/sane before I attempt to code it. Any advice is appreciated….

```
if [ try remote IP (ping data center 192.168.x.x) ]; then
    move on to the rest of the script

elif [ (ping data center does not work) try general internet connection (telnet or ping) ]; then    

    # general internet connection is up
    if [ check "VPN script" (if the process is running) ]; then
        if [ wait 1 minute to see if it kicks the tire to get the VPN connection up ]; then
            if it works and reconnects (ping) -  move on to the rest of the script
        else
            if not (ping) send an email to support that there is a problem
            then exit the script
        fi
    else (if "VPN script" process is not running)
        try to start it
                if [ it starts and connection comes up (ping) ]; then
                    move on to the rest of the script
                elif [ it starts and connection does not come up (ping)  ]; then
                    send an email that there is a problem
                    exit the script
                else
                    [ it does not start ]; then
                    send an email that there is a problem
                    exit the script
                fi
    fi

else (general internet connection is not up)
    exit the script

fi
```

Thanks --Rich

Answer (score 0):

I'd rearrange it somewhat to avoid code duplication of seeing if the VPN connection comes up.

```
if [ try remote IP (ping data center 192.168.x.x) ]; then
    move on to the rest of the script

elif [(ping data center does not work) try general internet connection (telnet or ping)]
then    

    # general internet connection is up
    if [ check "VPN script" (if "VPN script" process is not running) ]; then
        try to start it
        if [ it does not start ]; then
            send an email that there is a problem
            exit the script
        fi
    fi
    if [ wait 1 minute to see if it kicks the tire to get the VPN connection up ]; then
        if it works and reconnects (ping) -  move on to the rest of the script
    else
        if not (ping) send an email to support that there is a problem
        then exit the script
    fi

else (general internet connection is not up)
    exit the script

fi
```